# python setattr not checking if variable exists

Tags: python, variables, setattribute, setattr

test file:

```
my_name = ''
my_home_address = ''
my_home_phone = ''

my_office_address = ''
my_office_phone = ''
```

This another file, lets call it test2

```
import test

line1 = ['address', 'home', 'tom', 'downtown', '12345']
line1 = ['address', 'office', 'tom', 'uptown', '4567']

my_map = { 'home': ['my_name', 'my_home_address', 'my_home_phone'],
           'office1': ['my_name', 'my_office_address', 'my_office_phone'],
           'office2': ['my_name', 'my_office_address', 'my_office_phone'],
           }

if line1[1] in my_map.keys():
    for position, c_name in enumerate(line1):
        setattr(test, my_map[line1[1]][pos], my_map[line1[1]][pos])
```

Question: I have test file which has all the fields that save the data e.g.: `my_name = ''
my_home_address = '' my_home_phone = '' my_office_address = '' my_office_phone = ''` etc...

My input is `line1` which can have information in different formats but `line1[0]` and `line1[1]` is there for sure. 
`line1[1]` tells me what address it is. Now depending on `line1[1]` i will have to populate variables.

Problem I am facing: Since there are hundreds of Fields , sometimes I miss the spelling, Ex: instead of `'my_home_phone'`
i give it as `'my_hoe_phne'` , stil it loads the information in `test.my_hoe_phne = 4567`
Instead I want it to through error saying that this variable does not exist in test file. How do I achieve that?

"""

Comment: could just do a `hasattr` check before running `setattr`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before running `setattr`, you can do a quick check to see if the attribute exists on the module or not:

```
for pos, c_name in enumerate(line1):
    if not hasattr(test, my_map[line1[1]][pos]):
        raise AttributeError(
            'module `test` has no attribute %s' % my_map[line1[1]][pos])
    setattr(test, my_map[line1[1]][pos], my_map[line1[1]][pos])
```